# Why does the number of consecutive days counter *not* show what I expect?

Tags: support, profile-page, visited-days

While I would be proud to have a consecutive days counter of 1, as the screenshot shows it should at least be 3 for June alone. Why does it show as 1?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a bug.

The "consecutive days" counter is showing the **last** count of consecutive days, not the all time/week/month record.

So not visiting in the 12<sup>th</sup> of June caused the counter to reset.

Answer (score 9):

The "consecutive days" count refers to your *current* string of consecutive days visited, including today. So, since today is 13 June, and you did not visit yesterday (12 June), you only have one "consecutive day".

I believe, but am not certain, that days are considered on the basis of UTC 0000 to UTC 0000 - that is, if you are in (say) NYC, visiting at 1600 (4PM) today counts as a different day from visitng at 2200 (10PM) today - but visiting at 2200 today and visiting again at 1700 tomorrow counts as the same day.